# prime element $1-\zeta_5$

Tags: number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

We now that $\lambda = 1-\zeta_5$ is the unique prime obove $5$ in $Q(\zeta_5)$, I try to simplify, the congruence relation  $n \equiv 1 [\lambda^5]$ to be modulo an intger, is that possible ???

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Check first that the integers $1-\eta_5^k$, $k=1,2,3,4$, are all associate, that is, their pairwise quotients are integers and moreover units. Then check that 
$\prod_{k=1}^4(1-\eta_5^k) = 5$.

Comment: that prove the relation $(\lambda) ^4= 5$, my question is about the congruence relation modulo $\lambda^5$ if wi can transform it modulo an integer my friend

Comment: @Fouad El:  If $n$ is an integer then $n-1$ is divisible by some power of $5$, say $5^e$. Now $4 e \ge 5$ means $e\ge 2$. So I think you can replace by a congruence mod $25$.

Comment: I can't understand the two passages: - why if $n-1$ is divisible by some power of $5$ ???  - why $4e \geq 5$